# merging partition with ubuntu partition gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[gparted screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfhJg.png)
[image]
Can someone please help me in merging sda4 with sda8(ubuntu).

Comment: sda8 is mounted; you need to `umount` partitions for `gparted` to do resizing etc.  Personally I'd copy the data from sda4 to sda8 (whilst mounted), then reboot into 'live' & erase sda4 & expand sda8 to use the space that was used by sda4.  The erase/expand I'd do using a 'live' media, ie. Ubuntu install media.   Backup all data before hand (better safe than sorry; in case a truck destroyed power lines etc during resize etc).  If grub is owned by sda8 you may need to `grub-install` due to potential move of /boot, but I'd worry about that that only if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Merging" in the truest sense is not possible as far as i know.

What you can do:

1. Move all files from sda4 to sda8
2. delete sda4
3. move sda8 to where sda4 was and resize it (see screenshot)

[Screenshot showing resize option in context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3RPm.png)

There might be issues after you move your root partition but its not possible to predict the exact error/countermeasures.